# Utility to format text file into fixed width for Readme file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, text-formatting

We have a number of plain text, MS word, and pdf documents that we want to be formatted in fixed width / fixed cols format in a plain text file, similar to many readmes found out in the wild.  I have struggled to find anything via various google searches.  I can write some code to do it, but why reinvent the wheel if someone already has a util.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Just use Word and adjust the page margins.

Comment: That would work if we had MSWord (or compatible) available everywhere, but then whe wouldn't need txt file format.

Comment: I meant.  Use word to sent the margins then wave it was a RTF.  You tagged this as `Microsoft-Word `indicating you have access to it.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to MSWord to generate the plan text document that we want.  Plain text is the required output.

Answer (score 3):

Using Notepad++'s **Split Lines** functionality can do this for TEXT files.

1. Open your text file - your lines of text will either appear to go off the screen (if you have word wrapping off) or word wrapping will wrap your lines.
2. Resize your Notepad++ window to how wide you want the new "width" to be
3. `Ctrl + A` to select your entire document
4. Click `Edit` -> `Line Operations` -> `Split Lines` (or press `Ctrl + I`)

You may have to scroll horizontally to the start of the document but you will now have a "narrow" document.

I've absolutely no idea whether Notepad++ can do split lines to a predefined maximum number of columns (i.e. "split lines at 200 characters")

Comment: I will test this out on a real document, however using a garbage document, it appears that this works.  To get the "fixed columns" a little trial and error might do the trick.  I'll post back when i have a chance to test on the real thing.

Comment: Ok, i tried it with a "real" document, and as expected, it "works" but doesn't handle indentations for numbered or bulleted lists

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to either. A text document has no formatting so a bulleted list is cut and placed on a new line. You need a true word processor for advanced formatting.

Comment: Agreed.  We are using a word processor (MS Word).  Trying to find the tool that can format .doc/.docx into fixed width/column text with proper indentation.  I guess i can update the question to include that requirement (it is implied, not explicit).

Comment: The method provided here is a bridge.  It will do most of the heavy lifting.  Thanks for this info.

Answer (score -1):

@Big Chris: The number of characters depends on the NP++ Window width. Try to resize it before pressing `Ctrl + I`.